# How to get value of a gurobi variable in Python?

Tags: python, function, attributes, gurobi

I have a Gurobi variable, gama, in a function called recoveryd. I'd like to see what values this variable takes on at each call. What I've tried to access the attribute hasn't worked.

```
def RLD (Zednd):

    recoveryd = Model()
    recoveryd.setParam('OutputFlag', False)
  
    # Definition of decision variables
    O = recoveryd.addVars(dnode, timep, counter, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="O")
    X = recoveryd.addVars(arc, timep,counter, name="X")
    Zn = recoveryd.addVars(attnode,counter, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="Zn")
    Yn = recoveryd.addVars(attnode, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="Yn")
    gama = recoveryd.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name="gama")

    ### 
    for c in counter:
        recoveryd.addConstr((quicksum(mydict_weightn[(k, i,g)] * (mydict_phite[(k, i,g)] - 
        O[k, i, g,t, c]) for k, i, g in dnode for t in timep) / (14625.57) ) <= gama, 
        name="benders cut") # / demand
        
    # Definition of the objective function
    ZRLD = gama
    
    recoveryd.setObjective(ZRLD, GRB.MINIMIZE)
    recoveryd.optimize()
    

    # I want to output the value of gama  but this isn't working
    gamavalue = recoveryd.getAttr('X', gama)
    print("gamavalue =", gamavalue)

    # A similar setup for other Gurobi variable in this function works
    # recovery.printAttr('X')
    solutiondnode= recoveryd.getAttr('X', O)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Model.getAttr()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_getattr.html) method either expects a list or a dictionary of variables for the optional second argument. Your `gama` is just a single variable, not a list of variables.

Either pass a list to the method or directly access the variable's X attribute:

```py
# option 1: gamavalue is a list with one element
gamavalue = recoveryd.getAttr('X', (gama,))

# option 2: gamavalue is a float
gamavalue = gama.X
```